# Handling Null Values in subsample for Regression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, linear-regression

For my regression I make a lot of subsamples.
I like to know if there is function, to check wheter there are null values in my subsample. And only run the regression if there are no Null Values in the subsample. The regression should only run if I have the 30 days before my event.

I know how to get rid of the Null Values in my Subsample. But then I would either take <30 days or not excact 30 days before the event. 
This is my model which only should run if there is no Null value in the Dataframe  y. The index of y is the date and has one colmn with the relevant values.

```
    x= sm.add_constant (x)
    model= sm.OLS(y.astype(float), x.astype(float)).fit()
```

For performance reasons i like to avoid if statements.
Do you need more of my code to answer this question?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to check the size before doing the regression? Like:

```
if y[y.isull()].shape[0] < 30:
    x= sm.add_constant (x)
    model= sm.OLS(y.astype(float), x.astype(float)).fit()
```

Comment: i think this would work. To check this with an if statement. But maybe do you know something without if because this would take a lot of time because my dataset is very huge.

Comment: I highly doubt checking for nulls will be any performance bottleneck. Could you elaborate on what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i do the regression to estimate 'normal returns'. (it s called market model). And for this market model i need certain days before an event date to estimate my parameters. Unfortunatly sometimes i have no return data for certain companys. For the calculation of the normal returns I only like to have params which are estimated with this certain days before the event. My results would be falsify if i use other days or less days before the event.

Comment: I meant what is your expected output when facing a subsample with `nan`s?

Comment: This regression is in a for loop. I would save the company and the eventdate to list if there are null values in the subsample. But basically I dont need the output if there are nan in the subsample.

Comment: Then an `if` statement seems exactly what you need.